# Extracting string data present in single quote

Tags: java, regex

I am using java 7, and I have data stream containing following line:

```
SENDER='CALTRANS'
SENDER='BIGO'
SENDER='FIO'
..
..
```

I would like to extract only data present in single quote. i.e.

```
CALTRANS
BIGO
FIO
```

...
..

Any suggestion about Regular Expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably use the regex:

```
^SENDER='([^']+)'$
```

With the multiline flag. This regex matches the beginning of a line, followed by the text `SENDER='`, followed by anything that is not a single quote, followed by a single quote, followed by the end of the line.

```
String regex = "(?m)^SENDER='([^']+)'$";
```

So, you would print all of the matches from capturing group 1, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText); // inputText = "SENDER='CALTRANS'... etc"
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Something like `^[^=]+='([^']+)'$` might also be useful, if the value to the left of the equals sign can be something other than `SENDER`. That will match anything without an equals sign, followed by an equals sign, followed by something inside apostrophes that itself doesn't contain apostrophes. Phew. Reminds me of the saying, you think you have a problem and say "I'll solve it with a regexp", now you have two problems. (Though admittedly, for cases like this, they are *very* useful.)